# Nature of roots of self composed polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots

Suppose there is a polynomial $p(x)$ with degree $n.$
The problem is to tell the nature of the roots of the equation $p(p(x)) = 0$ if the nature of roots of the equation $p(x) = 0$ is given.

Particularly, what will be the nature of the roots of the equation $p(p(x)) = 0,$ if:

i) All roots of the equation $p(x) = 0$ are real

ii) All roots of the equation $p(x) = 0$ are complex

I tried as much as I can but I am not able to find a single general feature which allows me to move forward towards the solution.
What should I look for in this problem?

Comment: At the very least, (i) for $p(x)$ does not imply (i) for $p(p(x))$. However, if the coefficients of $p$ are real, then (ii) for $p(x)$ implies (ii) for $p(p(x))$

Comment: I am unable to understand how that follows, can you please explain more?

Comment: One thing is immediate to see. If $x=x_i$ satisfies $p(x)=0,$ then it also satisfies $p(p(x))=0.$ However, this is far from all you want since $p(p(x))$ is of degree $n^2.$ Thus, there are $n^2-n$ more roots (with possible multiplicities) to account for.

Comment: @Allawonder Yeah I tried if that helped in my problem in any way, it's clear that if $p(x)=0$ have roots say $α_i$ (i varies from 1 to n), then for the equation $p(p(x))=0$ to be true, it follows that $p(x) = α_i$ (i still varies from 1 to n) must be true, which converts the problem into finding solutions to the equation $p(x) - α_i = 0$ now I know that subtracting a constant from a function have a shifting effect, and that's where I get stuck, how can I predict how many roots come out to be real and how some complex?

Comment: @Allawonder - $p(x) = 0$ only implies $p(p(x)) = 0$ when $p(0) = 0$.

Comment: If $p$ has all real coefficients, then $p$ carries $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$. So if $p$ has no real roots, then for any real value $x, p(x)$ is also real, and therefore cannot be a root of $p(x)$. I.e., $p(p(x)) \ne 0$ for any real $x$. This is Hagen von Eitzen's second point.

Comment: @PaulSinclair And how's that different from what I said?

Comment: @Allawonder - I am pointing out that what you said is only true for polynomials satisfying $p(0) = 0$. You appeared to claim it was true for any polynomial.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Oh, I see what you mean now, and you're right!

Comment: As for Hagen von Eitzen's first point, a simple example is $p(x) = x^2 - 1/4$ which has real roots $\pm1/2$. However, $p(p(x)) = x^4 -1/2x^2 - 3/16$ has roots $\pm \sqrt 3 /2, \pm i/2$